# Not able to insert the data into SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

When trying to insert a row into a table with this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO CourierBooking 
VALUES (1001, 230, TO_DATE(sysdate() - interval '77' day), 'MUMBAI', 'delhi', 'HIGH', 300.0, 'BOOKED');
```

I'm getting this error

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that `sysdate()` should just be `sysdate`. Built-in functions with no arguments should not have parentheses when called; even though they are allowed (but optional) for PL/SQL functions with no arguments.

But you should not call `to_date()` on something that is already a date, as you are relying on implicit conversion and NLS settings. So

```
TO_DATE(sysdate()-interval '77' day)
```

should just be:

```
sysdate - interval '77' day
```

or just:

```
sysdate - 77
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=23f3b744715643eb269aa9802161837b)